# Tracking method "bloat" over time with nDepend

Tags: c#, powershell, ndepend

We are looking at using nDepend to start tracking some of our technical debt, particularly around hard to maintain methods and cyclomatic complexity.

I believe this is possibly by taking a baseline report and then running a new analysis to provide the delta. Below is a very basic Powershell I've put together that does this.

```
$nDepend = "C:\_DEVELOPMENT\nDepend\NDepend.Console.exe"
$targetFile = "C:\_DEVELOPMENT\AssemblyToTest\CodeChallenge.Domain.ndproj"
$projectFolder = Split-Path -Path $targetFile
$outputFolder = "nDepend.Reports"

$previous = ""
Clear-Host

# See if we already have a .ndar file in the output folder, if we do back it up so we can do a comparison
if (Test-Path $projectFolder\$outputFolder\*.ndar)
{
    Write-Output "Backing up previous NDAR report"
    Copy-Item $projectFolder\$outputFolder\*.ndar $projectFolder\previous.ndar
    $previous = ".\previous.ndar"
}

#The output path appears to be relative to the .ndproj file
& $nDepend $targetFile /Silent /OutDir .\$outputFolder /AnalysisResultToCompareWith .\previous.ndar
```

Here is the rule I've configured in nDepend: -

```
failif count > 1 bobs
from  m in Methods
where m.NbLinesOfCode > 10
where m.WasChanged()
select new { m, m.NbLinesOfCode }
```

The goal of this is not to break the build if we have methods over 10 lines, but rather to break the build if somebody edits an existing method that is too big and does not improve it (or make it worse). However the **where m.WasChanged()** part of the rule isn't being triggered regardless of how much code I add. If I comment it out it will alert me that there are plenty of methods that exceed 10 lines, but I only want to know about recently changed ones.

Am I using the rule wrong? Or perhaps my powershell is incorrectly using the **/AnalysisResultToCompareWith** parameter?

Answer (score 1):

There are default rules like [Avoid making complex methods even more complex](http://www.ndepend.com/default-rules/webframe.html?Q_Avoid_making_complex_methods_even_more_complex.html) in the rule group **Code Smells Regression** that are close to what you want to achieve. You can get inspired by their source code.

The key is to retrieve the methods changed with...

```
 m.IsPresentInBothBuilds() && 
 m.CodeWasChanged() &&
```

and then compare metric evolution since baseline by accessing `m.OlderVersion()`.

A [ICompareContext](http://www.ndepend.com/api/webframe.html?NDepend.API~NDepend.CodeModel.ICompareContext_members.html) reference two code bases snapshots the newer version and the older version. In this context the [OlderVersion()](http://www.ndepend.com/api/webframe.html?NDepend.API~NDepend.CodeModel.ICompareContext~OlderVersion.html) extension method returns actually calls the `ICompareContext.OlderVersion(codeElement)`, from the doc:

- Returns the older version of the `codeElement` object.
- If `codeElement` is already the older version, returns the `codeElement` object.
- If `codeElement` has been added and has no corresponding older version, returns `null`.
- This method has a constant time complexity.

Comment: Thanks Patrick! We'll try adding m.CodeWasChanged() 

Could you elaborate a little on what m.OlderVersion() is for though... I didn't quite follow you at the end there.

Comment: Updated hope this helps :)